# customize pdf preview with bootstrap and codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

I have this scenario in a collapse menu in bootstrap:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
  <h5 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Analisi Rischi Meccanici
    </button>
  </h5>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
  <div class="card-body">
        <object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
            Rischio gennaio 2019<br/><embed src="/cubo/Benvenuto.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
        </object>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
        <object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
            Aggiornamento Febbraio 2019<br/><embed src="/cubo/Benvenuto.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
        </object>
  </div>
</div>
```

i get this: [image]

my gentleman request are:
1) if its possible to zoom in the preview
2) if its possbile to put the preview one next to other not like the picture

I need this in few words a biggest preview than now:
[image]

thanks a lot
i whis that you can help me :)

thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for question 1):

```
<object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
        Rischio gennaio 2019<br/><embed src="/cubo/Benvenuto.pdf#zoom=100" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Set the zoom according to your preference and run.

Check the JS fiddle for question 2):

```css
.card_width {
width: 50%;
display: inline-block;
}

.float_right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
  <h5 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Analisi Rischi Meccanici
    </button>
  </h5>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
  <div class="card-body card_width">
        <object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
            Rischio gennaio 2019<br/><embed src="/cubo/Benvenuto.pdf#zoom=100" type="application/pdf" />
        </object>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body float_right card_width">
        <object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
            Aggiornamento Febbraio 2019<br/><embed src="/cubo/Benvenuto.pdf#zoom=100" type="application/pdf" />
        </object>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for replay but the question 1 is not about the zoom :) is about the preview I want a biggest preview :) can you help me ?

Comment: can you please make it a bit more clear what you mean by biggest preview

Comment: I have edited the question with an image for that I mean for a biggest preview :D can you help me now ? thanks a lot

Comment: ok you mean the width of the frame should be bigger..and inner should zoom or should it be of same size

Comment: exactly can you help me ?

Comment: sorry the frame bigger and the inner shoud zoom
can you help me ? thanks a lot